# A Grid Game with special moves allowed - ZCO 2009, P1

Tags: algorithm

> You are given a square grid of positive and negative numbers. You have to start at the top left corner of the grid and find a path to the bottom-right corner. In each step, you are only allowed to move one position to the right or one position down. As a special bonus, you are allowed at most one move that can be either to the left or up. Note that you are allowed to visit a position more than once as a result of this special move.
>
> Your aim is to find such a path that has the maximum weight, where the weight of a path is the sum of all the numbers visited along the path.

Greetings everybody! The above problem is a problem I could not solve :(

[Link to full Problem Here](https://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2009/zco2009/zco2009-1a.php)

Now, in my opinion, the main difficulty of this problem is in the special bonus move one can take. I am having difficulties on how to decide where the bonus move has to be made and how to proceed to take the most advantage of that move. I don' think a greedy algorithm would work here because we also have to take care of the future steps and not just locally optimum ones. I first thought of an algorithm that would use greedy approaches to move and arrive at the max value but again that does not seem to work.

Can anybody suggest me some methods on how to solve this problem and more problems like these? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is not written exactly there, but I suppose that the "standard move" cannot go to one location more than once and also that bonus move is not mandatory, right?

Comment: Do you know Dynamic programming? If removing the special move, can you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `f(i, j, w)` represent the best solution up to cell, `(i, j)` where `w` has one of three states: `before`, `after` and `right_after` a special move. Then generally:

```
f(i, j, before) = M(i, j) + max(
  f(i-1, j, before),
  f(i, j-1, before)
)

f(i, j, after) = M(i, j) + max(
  f(i-1, j, after),
  f(i, j-1, after),
  f(i-1, j, right_after),
  f(i, j-1, right_after)
)

f(i, j, right_after) = M(i, j) + max(
  f(i+1, j, before),
  f(i, j+1, before)
)
```

JavaScript code (not memoised, bottom-up left to the reader):

```js
function f(M, i, j, w){
  if (i == 0 && j == 0 && w != 'right_after')
    return M[i][j]
  
  if (i < 0 || i > M.length-1 ||
    j < 0 || j > M[0].length-1)
    return -Infinity
    
  if (w == 'before'){
    return M[i][j] + Math.max(
      f(M, i-1, j, 'before'),
      f(M, i, j-1, 'before'))
  }
  
  if (w == 'after'){
    return M[i][j] + Math.max(
      f(M, i-1, j, 'after'),
      f(M, i, j-1, 'after'),
      f(M, i-1, j, 'right_after'),
      f(M, i, j-1, 'right_after'))
  }

  if (w == 'right_after'){
    return M[i][j] + Math.max(
      f(M, i+1, j, 'before'),
      f(M, i, j+1, 'before'))
  }
}

var M = [
  [12, -16, 10, -12],
  [-16, 13, -14, 7],
  [7, -4, 16, -15],
  [-7, 16, -9, 8]
]

var m = M.length
var n = M[0].length

console.log(Math.max(
  f(M, m-1, n-1, 'before'),
  f(M, m-1, n-1, 'after')
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the special move, you would solve this for each cell by taking the max of its left and up neighbors' cumulative weights. Extend this idea by creating a nxnx3 matrix, Where the center of the 3 is the nxn input, and the other 2 are shifted to represent the 2 possible special moves. Then fill out the middle grid as usual. Ditto for the extra grids with the max being taken from the up or left neighbor as usual, but also from the cell's neighbor in the central grid. Finish by taking the max of the bottom-right element of the three grids.